# Why does "Shokugeki no Soma" get so many full colored chapters?

Tags: manga-production, shokugeki-no-soma

I've never seen a manga with so many full-color chapters. I believe for *Fuuka*, *Kimi no Iru Machi*, *Suzuka* (all of them by the same author), and also many other manga only have a few pages of color manga when there is a color edition.

Yet, from chapter 116 to 134 (as of writing), all of the chapters have another version that is in full-color. From my perspective, this is very unusual. I understand that it is a very popular manga, but manga I listed above and other manga are just or even more popular, but none to my knowledge have had this many strings of full-colored publications.

Is there a reason to this or did the author/artist just have a lot of extra time to devote to coloring in the manga?

Answer (score 0):

I think that they come from this [digital magazine](http://plus.shonenjump.com/ext/wj.html), which is done by [Shueisha Inc.](http://www.shueisha.co.jp/english/). So that means, it is done by neither the artist nor the author. I also think that it might just be because of the anime gaining popularity that they are trying to bolster the manga also. That's my two cents at least.